# postmaster: could not access directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data": Permission denied

Tags: postgresql

/var/lib/pgsql　配下のファイルをすべて、拡張ディスク（/mnt/bv1/data/pgsql）に移動し、/var/lib/pgsql をシンボリックリンクに変更しました。拡張ディスクに移動したファイルは、オーナーをpostgres,パーミッションを755に変更しています。
この状態で、サービスを起動すると、postmaster: could not access directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data": Permission denied　となり、起動できません。
パーミッションの問題のようなので、拡張ディスクに移動したファイルのパーミッションを777に変更しても同じエラーになってしまいます。

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 postgres           postgres             19 Jun  8 11:02 pgsql -> /mnt/bv1/data/pgsql
```

実施した手順

1. mv /var/lib/pgsql/* /mnt/bv1/data
2. chmod -R 755 /mnt/bv1/data
3. ln -s /mnt/bv1/data/pgsql /var/lib
4. sudo service postgrtesql start

バージョン
・10.23

Comment: サービスの起動は具体的にどのようなコマンドを実行したかを追記してください。また、念のため OS に関する情報 (種類やバージョン等) も記載があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: 時間もなかったので、以下の方法で起動させています。
1. cp -ap /var/lib/pgsql /mnt/bv1
2. /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf の以下書き換え 
    data_directory = '/mnt/bv1/pgsql/data'
3. sudo restorecon -R /mnt/bv1
4. sudo service postgtresql start

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/pgsql/` の中身を`/mnt/bv1/data/` に移動しているので、シンボリックリンクの貼り方が間違っている気がします。

今の状態からシンボリックリンクを貼り直すなら…

```
# rm /var/lib/pgsql
# ln -s /mnt/bv1/data /var/lib/pgsql
```

(参考) 本来実行すべきだったコマンド例:

```
# mv /var/lib/pgsql /mnt/bv1/data
# ln -s /mnt/bv1/data/pgsql /var/lib/pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

SELinux が有効なのですね。

移動先は /mnt/bv1/data/ ですか？ /mnt/bv1/data/pgsql/ ですか？
前者と仮定すると以下の手順になると思います。

```
[root@host]# cp -a /var/lib/pgsql/* /mnt/bv1/data/
[root@host]# ls /mnt/bv1/data/
backups  data

[root@host]# semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/pgsql  /mnt/bv1/data
[root@host]# restorecon -R /mnt/bv1/data/

    /mnt/bv1/data を /var/lib/pgsql と同じコンテキストとする。

[root@host]# mv /var/lib/pgsql /var/lib/pgsql.bak
[root@host]# ln -s /mnt/bv1/data /var/lib/pgsql
[root@host]# ls -ld /var/lib/pgsql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13  6月  9 21:07 /var/lib/pgsql -> /mnt/bv1/data
[root@host]# restorecon /var/lib/pgsql

    シンボリックリンク自体のコンテキストも修正が必要。
```